# How to export routes in node.js and express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My problem is not in the question totally, but it's in the same page.
So I exported a route to my main `app.js` file but the my post route isn't working. My problems are below the code because I need you to read the code in order to be clear.

This is my file from where i will export the route(registration.js):

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
console.log("azerty");
router.post("/register", (req, res)=>{
    console.log("qwerty");
    res.stautus(200).send("hello");
});
module.exports = router;
```

This is my main file to where i will export the route (app.js):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
...
app.use("/register", require("./registration.js"));
```

This is my html form:

```
<form action="/register" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fstName" required/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lstName"required/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I have some other issues related to this:

- first: why does `azerty` log to the console when I'm at
  `http://localhost:3000/`?
- second: why I keep getting `Cannot POST /register` and in the developer tool a `404` error? And my code inside the route handler doesn't run.
- lastly: Is this the right way to export routes(like using the `express.Route()` in the routing file and `express()` only in the main one)?

Comment: Typo - `res.stautus(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> first: why does azerty log to the console when I'm at http://localhost:3000/?

`console.log("azerty")` is in file scope of `registration.js`, so will be logged as soon as your `app.js` requires it.

This line here is enough to triger the console logging: `app.use('/register', require('./registration'));` becuase module is required when express mounts it as middleware on start

> second: why I keep getting Cannot POST /register and in the developer tool a 404 error? And my code inside the route handler doesn't run.

Becuase it is *not mounted* where you think it is mounted.

`router.post("/register ...` Here you've mounted at `/register` path, and then `app.use("/register", require("./registration.js"));` here you've mounted to another `/register` path. Combine the two together, you get full path as `/register/register` (Also check the typo mentioned in comment)

So to mount at `localhost:3000/register`, you've to define like (Note the differences):

```
router.post("/", (req, res)=>{ ...

// and then
app.use("/register", require("./registration.js"));

// or simply
router.post("/register", (req, res)=>{ ...

// and then
app.use(require("./registration.js"));
```

> lastly: Is this the right way to export routes(like using the express.Route() in the routing file and express() only in the main one)?

Yes, it's perfectly fine. But keep in mind the mount path.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess my knowledge of middlewares is little.

Answer (score 2):

I think you added a prefix to the route with app.use("/register"...) and now it is /register/register

Juste remove it in app.js or in your route file

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
console.log("azerty");
router.post("/register", (req, res)=>{
    console.log("qwerty");
    res.stautus(200).send("hello");
});
module.exports = router;
```

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
...

app.use(require("./registration.js"));
```

I don't know if it is the right way here's what i do its kinda like you

```js
//src/app.js
// Import
import postRoutes from './routes/post';
import authRoutes from './routes/auth';

...
// Endpoints

app.use(postRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);
```

```js
// src/routes/post.js

...

const Router = express.Router();

/**
 * Routes
 */

Router.get('/post', getPosts);
Router.post('/post', isAuth,  creationValidation(), createPost);
Router.put('/post/:id', isAuth, editValidation(), putPost);
Router.delete('/post/:id', isAuth, deletePost);



/**
 * Export
 */
export default Router;
```

Comment: Thank you it was the `/register` problem, it's not totally what i want but it's just that i want it the other way: it's answered above. Now i have a clear idea on prefixes. And in your code  there is `export default Router`, can you explain me what does it mean, especially the `default` please?

Comment: It's the ES6 version of module.exports = router 
If you want to know more you can check this link 
https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f

Answer (score 1):

`azerty` was logged to the console that means the route was imported and it worked.

You have already exported the route in the right way.
I think you shoud use `return` before `res.stautus(200).send("hello");` in **`registation.js`**.
Like that:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
console.log("azerty");
router.post("/", (req, res)=>{
    console.log("qwerty");
    return res.stautus(200).send("hello");
});
module.exports = router;
```

To use this request, the api looks like: `localhost:3000/register`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `azerty` is getting logged because it's not nested inside any functions. It will simply log on runtime and you being at `http://localhost:3000/` has no influence on this.

Second, you `Cannot POST /register` because when using router, the root is the first parameter passed to `app.use` - in your current setup, `/register/register` is the route.
To fix this, change the first parameter of `router.post` in `registration.js` to just `/`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
console.log("azerty");
router.post("/", (req, res)=>{
    console.log("qwerty");
    res.status(200).send("hello");
});
module.exports = router;
```

Finally, for exporting routes this is the most common setup I see.

Comment: Thank you it worked just fine. But I still don't get why `azerty` is logged: I didn't call the file to run only if it's `http://localhost:3000/register` using `app.use("/register", require("./registration.js"))`

Comment: It gets logged when you import it in `app.js`, the whole file gets evaluated once when you import it, causing the `console.log` message to appear.I think you're misunderstanding, `router.post` is a function called once, which tells express what to do for all future requests on that path, it doesn't go back to the file to look again.